# python -v not returning anything in Cygwin

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin

I am trying to run `python3.6.8` in `cygwin`.

Typing `python -v` just results in the terminal window hanging. I have to escape out of it to make it respond further.

Typing `python36 -v` results in the error `python36 command not found`. I definitely installed this module while installing `Cygwin`.

I notice in /cygdrive/c, only python27 seems to be present. Running python -i also shows me that 2.7 is installed.

I want to run 3.6.8, have tried reinstalling multiple times, same issue.

Running "which python" shows only

```
/cygdrive/c/Python27/python
```

How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: You should use `python -V` to see the version info. Try also `python3 -V`. However ... It looks like you do not have the cygwin python 2.7 installed, because `/cygdrive/c/Python27/python` is the windows version of python. You need to run cygwin setup again to install the python package you want.

Answer (score 0):

Generally all the python versions with 3 can be accessed using python3 as binary. In windows often the path variable doesn't hold the python3 binary path so the binary is not called.

do

```
echo $PATH | grep python
```

Check for the version of the python if python36 is present then do

```
python3 --version
```

Comment: Hmm, the first command has no results. The second says "python3 : command not found". Very odd behaviour. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @SimonKiely the issue is with the path variable and not the installation. In cygwin this happens. May I suggest you to use Mobaxterm community edition -- this is far better than cygwin and you won't face such issues. Install mobaxterm and then install using apt. Mobaxterm supports apt.

Answer (score 0):

Look in `/usr/bin` for all python exe's. Use `ls -l /usr/bin/python*.*`. I suspect you will not find `python3.6m.exe`.

Run cygwin setup again and select the `python3.6` package. You can also install a version of 3.7, 3.8 or some older ones if you wish. You can only get the latest release of the e.g. 3.6 series.